# Getting rid of "Sign in to iMessages" popup at boot in Mac OS Catalina

Tags: icloud, catalina, apple-id

I have recently logged out of my apple id account and icloud in my MacBook Pro MAC OS Catalina. But this message keeps popping up asking me to update the password for my apple id for iMessages:

[image]

Apparently there are still traces of my Apple ID somewhere in the system. I don't want this message to popup everytime and I want all the traces to be gone without re-installing MAC. I have already followed the instruction for a similar problem here: [How do I remove an iMessage account from OS X (Yosemite) Messages app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/181742/how-do-i-remove-an-imessage-account-from-os-x-yosemite-messages-app), However the files do not exist in the paths the post mentions (in MAC OS Catalina).